# Correctness of "Let go!"

Tags: grammaticality, imperatives

I yelled *Let go!* to my son while he was pulling his sister's arm. My husband says it's incorrect. I have no idea. Is it correct?

Comment: perhaps this is [general reference](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%5B3%5D)?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=define+"let go"

Comment: GR Voting to close.

Comment: Did your husband give any reason why it sounded incorrect to him? Does he think it should be 'Let go of her!' or something else?

Comment: Yes he said it was incorrect because it was incomplete.

Comment: It sounds okay to me.

Comment: @Elizabeth: It's not incomplete. Its just like 'Help!'. If you want to add the object, then great, but really, whatever is happening is obvious (let go of whatever it is you're holding on to, or help me with whatever looks to be the matter).

Answer (score 8):

Well, it's in the OED (1973 edition).

> 22 Let go
>
> a *trans.* To allow to escape; to set at liberty; to lose one's hold of; to relax (one's hold); to drop (an anchor).
>
> ...
>
> b *intr.* = to let go one's hold.
>
> ...

I'm afraid your husband is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

To *[let go](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/let-go)* is to stop holding something. One can say

> Let go of her arm!

or simply

> Let go!

for short.